withdrawing ERC20 tokens from a contract?
A smart contract which stores ERC20 tokens. When withdrawing an amount from the contract I found examples of checking the token balance before making the transfer:
IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenAddress);
uint256 contractBalance = token.balanceOf(address(this));
require(contractBalance >= amount, "Insufficient token balance in contract");

In the ERC20 implementation itself there is a check for the token balance in _update:
uint256 fromBalance = _balances[from];
if (fromBalance < value) {
  revert ERC20InsufficientBalance(from, fromBalance, value);
}

As I understand it if the contract happens to have less of the token balance than the amount, the transaction would revert with the error message of the ERC20 standard anyway.
Isn't it wasteful to check for the balance twice?

Probably the code require(contractBalance >= amount, "Insufficient token balance in contract");will be executed early and this error will be raised. I guess this is really wasteful, I see no scenario where this double check is useful. Just not sure wich option minimize gas.

The waste is relatively small, assuming new higher throughput Ethereum L2 chains, so no big harm done.
Giving users a better error message is always helpful and desired.
